# Add Windows Authentication Header to HTTP-Request for WebDAV Authentication

Tags: authentication, ms-word, http-headers, windows-authentication, webdav

In my web project I use the WebDAV component of the Microsoft Internet Information Server 7.5 for document processing with Microsoft Word.

One of the main problems currently and in the past was to design the authentication in such a way that no dialog for entering the user and password appears in Word.

I'm currently solving the authentication problem by adding a header for basic authentication to every WebDAV request on the server side in a separate IHttpModule.

My own module is integrated in the web.config as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests="true">
    <add name="WebDAVHttpModule" type="WebDAVHttpModule.WebDAVHttpModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The code for server-side authentication is exemplary as follows:

```
Private Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim oHttpApplication As HttpApplication = DirectCast(source, HttpApplication)

    gsWebDAV_User = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("XXX\Options").GetValue("WebDAV_User")
    gsWebDAV_PWD = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("XXX\Options").GetValue("WebDAV_PWD")
        gsLogin = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(gsWebDAV_User & ":"
                     & CipherTools.gsDecipher(gsWebDAV_PWD, "RijndaelManaged")))

    oHttpApplication.Context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + gsLogin)


End Sub
```

However, Microsoft Office 365 will soon no longer support basic authentication.

Is there a way to append a Windows authentication header to every WebDAV request so that the login dialog no longer appears when opening a Word document via a browser?